# Can I use forEach to change many variables?

Tags: javascript

I've to calculate some variables and want to minify the code. Here is my current code:

```
z = a+b+c+d+e+f;   // a-f are integer numbers
a = Math.round(a/z*100)+20;
b = Math.round(b/z*100)+20;
c = Math.round(c/z*100)+20;
d = Math.round(d/z*100)+20;
e = Math.round(e/z*100)+20;
f = Math.round(f/z*100)+20;
```

Is there a way to minify the code to

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f].forEach(function(i) { Math.round(i/z*100)+20; } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map and destructure the result to their variables:

- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a new array with a value for each item,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), for getting the value off the result into the variables, wiht
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as a little halp to add all values from an array.

```js
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4,
    e = 5,
    f = 6,
    z = [a, b, c, d, e, f].reduce((a, b) => a + b);

[a, b, c, d, e, f] = [a, b, c, d, e, f].map(i => Math.round(i / z * 100) + 20);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
console.log(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let a =1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6;
let z = a+b+c+d+e+f;

let op = [a,b,c,d,e,f].map(e=> Math.round(e/z*100)+20);

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object or array instead, and then you can use an array method to transform or reassign all the desired properties. For example:

```
const initialArr = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
const transformedArr = initialArr.map(num => Math.round(num/z*100)+20);
```

`transformedArr[0]` will correspond to `a`, `transformedArr[1]` will correspond to `b`, and so on. (Ideally, you'd *start* with all those variables in an array from the beginning.)